# How to create form using shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form

I want to access a wordpress form that I created using `Contact Form 7` in my Facebook Page Tab application. My question is if I create a simple file test.php and put the shortcode for contact Form 7 form there and then access the `test.php` in cavnas URL in my `facebook app`, does the form appear?

How can I achieve this?

How can I simply display the form in test.php?

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD 1**

- You can add the form in a page on your site by using its short code
- Now copy the URL of that page on your WordPress site
- Load that URL using IFRAME in Facebook

iframe code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.yourdomain.com/test.php"> 
 </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**METHOD 2**

- You can create the form in contact form 7 and copy its short code.
- Now install a plugin called "[Facebook Tab Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-tab-manager/)" and activate it.
- Facebook Tab Manager will help you easily embed your WordPress site content to your Facebook page.

Comment: facebook itselfs show my page in a Canvas URL, iFrame, there is already a frame there

Comment: please share the exact location where you want to implement the form. I can help you more quickly

Comment: I am showing abc.php in my canvas app , now with in that page I want to redirect my wordpress.. I want to show the wordpress page inside my facebook app.. how can I do that?